# SQL Server - Split a row into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 table which represents lines of orders.
It looks like this (simplified version):

```
LineId ProductId Quantity MaxQuantityInPackage
1      ProductA  160      160
2      ProductB  20       50
3      ProductC  220      100
```

Here is the result i need :

```
LineId ProductId Quantity MaxQuantityInPackage
1      ProductA  160      160
2      ProductB  20       50
3      ProductC  220      100
3      ProductC  220      100
3      ProductC  220      100
```

As you can see, i need a row by package for each product line.
ProductC needs 3 packages, so it has to be split into 3 rows.

I found some hints out there, based on temporary tables or T-SQL script.

But in my case, i use this query in a software to create reports (bills).
This software do not allow me to use complex functions, and i feel lucky to still have access to UNION function.

How can i achieve this in the most simple way ?

Thank you for your replies.
JiceY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a numbers table with integers from 1 to the largest number you will need.

Then you can use

```
SELECT oi.*
FROM   OrderItems oi
       JOIN Numbers n
         ON n.Number <= CEILING(1.0 * Quantity / MaxQuantityInPackage)
```

If you are unable to create tables you can include a derived one inline.

```
SELECT oi.*
FROM   OrderItems oi
       JOIN (SELECT 1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 3
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 4
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 5
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 6
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 7
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 8
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 9
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 10) n(Number)
         ON n.Number <= CEILING(1.0 * Quantity / MaxQuantityInPackage)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly the hint that i needed !